# Find item in list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dictionary` something like this:

```
list = [
   {
      "ENT_AUT":[
         "2018-11-27"
      ]
   },
   {
      "ENT_NAT_REF_COD":"C87193"
   },
   {
      "ENT_NAM":"MONEYBASE LIMITED"
   },
   {
      "ENT_NAM_COM":"MONEYBASE LIMITED"
   },
   {
      "ENT_ADD":"Ewropa Business Centre, Triq Dun Karm"
   },
   {
      "ENT_TOW_CIT_RES":"Birkirkara"
   },
   {
      "ENT_POS_COD":"BKR 9034"
   },
   {
      "ENT_COU_RES":"MT"
   }
]
```

Here every `dictionary` will always contain only one key value pair. Now I need to know the value of `ENT_NAM`, `ENT_AUT` and etc all fields.

I tried something like this:

```
ENT_NAM = (list[2].values())[0]
print('ENT_NAM = ', ENT_NAM)
```

It works perfectly for this list but my problem is that the  'ENT_NAM' containing dictionary **will not always be on the 2nd index** of the list. **How can I generalize this solution so that even if the order of the dictionary under the list changes, I always find a perfect solution?**

Comment: Why is your data in this bizarre format in the first place?  Since all the keys are different, they should all be in a single dict, in which case your problem disappears.

Comment: @jasonharper sadly it's quite common to get things like this from api calls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the keys are unique, you can flatten the list of dictionaries into a dictionary with a straightforward dictionary comprehension.

Note: you don't want to use `list` as a name for a variable, as it is an important built-in type. Use something like `lst` instead.

```
{ k: v for d in lst for k, v in d.items() }
```

Result:

```
{'ENT_AUT': ['2018-11-27'], 'ENT_NAT_REF_COD': 'C87193', 
 'ENT_NAM': 'MONEYBASE LIMITED', 'ENT_NAM_COM': 'MONEYBASE LIMITED', 
 'ENT_ADD': 'Ewropa Business Centre, Triq Dun Karm', 
 'ENT_TOW_CIT_RES': 'Birkirkara', 'ENT_POS_COD': 'BKR 9034', 
 'ENT_COU_RES': 'MT'}
```

Getting the value for key `'ENT_NAM'` is now just:

```
{ k: v for d in lst for k, v in d.items() }['ENT_NAM']
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a search problem.  Here the naive solution is probably fine:

```py
def get_prop(dicts, k):
    return next(x[k] for x in dicts if k in x)

get_prop(l, "ENT_NAM")
```

Incidentally, don't call your variable `list`: it shadows a builtin.

If you need to use this data more than about 3 times I would just reduce it to a dict:

```py
def flatten(dicts):
    iterdicts = iter(dicts)
    start = next(iterdicts)
    for d in iterdicts:
        start.update(d)
    return start


one_dict = flatten(list_of_dicts)
one_dict["ENT_NAM"]
```

(There are plenty of other ways to flatten a list of dicts, I just currently think the use of `iter()` to get a consumable list is neat.)

Comment: Agreed on your last comment. This is much nicer than a comprehension in my opinion. There's also `functools.reduce(operator.or_, list_of_dicts)` too :D

Comment: @ddejohn ooh, neat, I had a brief thought about a single iterator but forgot about `operator`.  Although you need to be running >3.10 for the | syntax to work.

Comment: True. Of course `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: {**x, **y}, list_of_dicts)` would work too :D (I'm a big fan of functional programming if you couldn't tell lol)

Answer (score 2):

As jasonharper said in the comments, if it is possible, the data should be formulated as a single dictionary.

If this cannot happen, you can retrieve the value of `ENT_NAM` using:

```py
print(list(filter(lambda elem: "ENT_NAM" in elem.keys(), my_list))[0]["ENT_NAM"])
```

Returns:

```
MONEYBASE LIMITED
```

*Note: `list` has been renamed to `my_list` since list is a reserved Python keyword*

Comment: Minor correction: `list` isn't a keyword, it's just a built-in function. Python won't let you use keywords as variable names because keywords are what make up the language's grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @ddejohn you are absolutely right.